# Linked lists in C zero at the end and beginning of the list

Tags: c, linked-list

I am new to the linked lists in C. I have created a code where you can add members to the beginning of the list, add members to the end of the list, and printing the lists. the code reads a character input from the user a,b, or p. a will add to the begging of the list. b to the end. p for printing the list. but for some reason when I do adding there's an unwanted 0 that comes as a result either to the begging of the list or the end of it. any ideas why is that?

Input:

```
>a
>6
>p
```

Output:

```
>The list: 6 0
```

The desired output should be

```
>The list: 6
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct node {
    int val;
    struct node * next;
} node_t;

void displayList(node_t * head);
void push(node_t * head, int number);
void pushfront(node_t ** head, int val);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int num;
    char c;

    node_t * head = NULL;
    head = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    if (head == NULL) 
    {
        return 1;
    }

    while (c != 'q')
    {

        scanf("%c", &c);
        if (c =='b')
        {
            scanf("%d", &num);
            push(head, num);
        }


        if (c=='a')
        {
            scanf("%d", &num);
            pushfront(&head,num);

        }


        if (c=='p')
        {
            printf("The list: ");
            displayList(head);
        }

    }


    return 0;
}

void displayList(node_t * head)
{

    node_t * p = head;

    while(p != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ", p->val);
        p=p->next;
    }


}


//adding item to the end of the list
void push(node_t * head, int number)
{
    node_t * current = head;
    while (current->next != NULL) {
        current = current->next;
    }

    /* now we can add a new variable */
    current->next = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    current->next->val = number;
    current->next->next = NULL;
}

//add item to the beginning of the list
void pushfront(node_t ** head, int val)
{
    node_t * new_node;
    new_node = malloc(sizeof(node_t));

    new_node->val = val;
    new_node->next = *head;
    *head = new_node;
}
```

Comment: What is the *first* thing you do *before* the read-loop to build your list? `head = malloc(sizeof(node_t));` **That** node doesn't actually hold user-data, but *does* get printed per your `displayList` implementation.

Comment: what do you mean by "doesn't actually hold user-data" ?

Comment: Exactly and literally what I said, is what I meant. Every loop iteration you "push" a new node containing a char into the list. The *initial* node in the list, the one assigned to `head` with the exact code I cited, *before* that loop operation, has no data from the user. It just sits there (and you push algorithms require it that way). Your `displayList` prints everything, *including* that node. I have no idea why this was moderator-put-on-hold, btw. It clearly has enough data to discuss possible answers.

Comment: I already had head set to NULL

Comment: `head = malloc(sizeof(node_t));` is not NULL. the prior initialization is irrelevant after that. Again, that node contains *no* user data, but is included in your print mechanics.

Comment: what is that line doing bro? `node_t * head = NULL; `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200764/discussion-between-bishoy-akmal-and-whozcraig).

Comment: Ultimately, it does *nothing* because the value of `head` is *immediately* overwritten by the next line (which I've now cited twice).

Comment: [See this example](https://pastebin.com/p3XyuVLi). Still not ideal, but closer to what you probably are seeking. Includes fixing the failure to skip whitespace on character-read and using pass-by-address for both push operations.

Comment: head is not used at all. Try setting the value at -1 and print the list afterwards: you'll get -1. The 0 is probably the value (uninitialized) of head.

Comment: besides, a better [mcve] would not have interactive input (and your interface is misleading like hell) but rather calls with fixed values. So everyone can reproduce and debug.

Comment: also: when list is empty, displayList should mention it... and add a linefeed in the end.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I am doing this code to be tested on a compiler that uses specific inputs and outputs to be valid only if input and output matches. if I printed anything to be 'interactive' with the user, this printed stuff will be considered as an output with the result and will not be assumed to be valid. I know what you mean that the interface is not interactive. I meant so for a reason.

Comment: the fact that it's interactive is one of the reasons you're not getting any answer right now